# What is the power lost per foot?

Tags: resistors

This question seems trivial and i think i am overlooking something but for whatever reason i cant figure it out.

A city requires 1010W of power at 110V. Assuming 1 foot diameter transmission
cables which has .05 micro ohms per foot resistivity, calculate
power lost per foot.

I've tried taking the derivative of \$P=\frac{V^2}{R}\$ where \$R=0.05\cdot10^{⁻6} × l\$.

I get \$\frac{\text{d}P}{\text{d}l} = \frac{-V^2}{0.05\cdot10^{⁻6} × l^2}\$  which seems like it would be correct but I dont think that give the lost per foot.

Comment: Your numbers don't make much sense. First, 1000 W at 110 V is about 10 A. That's not a city, that's like one microwave oven. Second, the units of resistivity are Ohms x meters (or Ohms x feet, if you want to play it that way), not Ohms per foot. Can you clarify whether the number you have is the resistivity or the resistance per foot?

Comment: @ThePhoton: Unfortunately, now that the user has their answer, I don't think we'll ever see him/her again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need any derivatives or integration.

Remember the formula, \$\displaystyle R = \rho\frac{\ell}{A}\$?

This formula is used for calculating the resistance of a conductor given resistivity (\$\displaystyle \rho\$), length of the conductor (\$\displaystyle \ell\$), and cross-sectional area (A). You need to use this formula to find resistance.

Once you've set up your equations (the one above, and the power equation you posted), you can solve for what the power loss is for \$\displaystyle \ell = 1 ft\$.

Personally I'd convert all those measurements to metric before anything else.

Comment: So does that mean that my final equation is P = V^2 / (.05E-6 * 1)?

Comment: Thanks for the accept, but you should wait in case any other answers come in [or if I'm shown to be wrong - wouldn't be the first time :) ]. In response to your question, I haven't done the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it as follows:

Calculate the current through the line:

\$I=\dfrac{P}{V}\$

And then use the R/foot to calculate the power/foot.

\$P=I^2R\$

This assumes that the R/foot is resistance / foot of length of transmission line.

If it's resistivity, then it's a bit ambiguous, because resistivity is usually Ohm meters, not Ohm/meter.

It would then be necessary to plug the resistivity into \$\displaystyle R = \rho\frac{\ell}{A}\$ and then use that R.